# How to debug Cocoa application that crashes before main loop only when breakpoints are enabled?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, crash, debugging, breakpoints

I have a Cocoa application that works when run in both debug and release mode, but crashes as soon as I run it in debug mode with breakpoints enabled. The crash happens before the app has finished loading, and the stack trace hints at a KVO problem. Unfortunately, since the crash happens outside of my code, all I can see in the debugger are the (generic) method names and assembly code. How do I go about finding the root cause?

Stack trace:

```
#0   0x98dde4e6 in objc_exception_throw
#1   0x943443e8 in +[NSException raise:format:arguments:]
#2   0x9434435a in +[NSException raise:format:]
#3   0x9092bc49 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) _removeObserver:forProperty:]
#4   0x9092b864 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) removeObserver:forKeyPath:]
#5   0x938a8a63 in -[NSController removeObserver:forKeyPath:]
#6   0x0037807a in dyld_stub_write
#7   0x00378b0e in dyld_stub_write
#8   0x003774d6 in dyld_stub_write
#9   0x003775fe in dyld_stub_write
#10  0x936b8c3b in -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate]
#11  0x936b8a49 in -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:]
#12  0x936b7d4e in -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:]
#13  0x936b61f4 in loadNib
#14  0x936b55ed in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:]
#15  0x936b54fe in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:]
#16  0x936b5449 in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:]
#17  0x936b224d in NSApplicationMain
#18  0x00001f68 in main at main.m:13
```

Comment: You have an exception, not a crash. The exception may then lead to crash, but I'm not sure you're clear on the difference. Is it that with breakpoints off the exception is thrown, but caught internally?

Comment: @Mike Abdullah: Fair enough. I am familiar with the distinction, but it hadn't occurred to me that the exception might be handled internally (in some library code, perhaps?). Using exceptions for regular program flow in Cocoa apps is discouraged because stack unwinding is quite expensive in Objective-C. If that is indeed what is happening, then I will have to look closely at all of the 3rd party libraries I am using. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the bottom of the stack. This is nib loading code. Given the KVO at the top of the stack, my first guess would be that you connected something to an outlet or through bindings but didn't properly define the property you connected to. Make sure you include accessors for any properties you define.